# Firestore rules : getting permission denied on empty collection with defined rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, permissions, firebase-security, permission-denied

I'm struggling with a permission denied in my firestore rules and can't figure out why I get this one. Here it how it happens :

I got a collection named `invitations` in my firestore database. Right now, this collection has no document at all in it.

I'm writting rules for it anyway, using this simple example, to get invitations with my `uid` as `userId` property:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /invitations/{invitationId} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId;
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to get my collection, with a specific query that only gets invitations with my `uid`, I'm getting a permission denied error from firestore. It happens even when my collection is empty. When i set condition like `allow read: if true;`, no more error is showing.

I also tried this condition that returns false

```
allow read: if invitationId == 'idOfMyOnlyInvitation';
```

or

```
allow read: if resource.data.id == 'idOfMyOnlyInvitation';
```

Does someone have a clue about this problem ? Thanks in advance for your help and your time.

Answer (score 0):

My query was messed up. Sorry for disturbing.